# Всем привет! Есть вопрос насчёт того, как задать матрицу столбцами?

Tags: javascript, массивы, матрицы

Есть некая фраза с n количеством символов(пусть будет ",единица языка,"), которую надо занести в матрицу как на скрине

[image: Пример полученной матрицы]

```
    var obj2 = {}

for (let a = 0; a < matrici; a++) { //создаём матрицу для расшифровки
    let matrix2 = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        matrix2[i] = new Array();
        for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix2[i][j] = shifr[i];
        }
        shifr = shifr.slice(3);
        obj2["matrixSec"+a] = matrix2;
    }
}
console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text = ",единица языка,";
var rows = 3;
var cols = Math.ceil(text.length / rows);
var x = new Array(rows);
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i] = new Array(cols);
}
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  x[i%rows][Math.floor(i/rows)]=text[i];
}
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с визуализацией.

Чем-то похож на ответ от [Алексея Р](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1467087/221218), вот только использует один цикл.

```js
var word = ',единица языка,'.split('');
var row = 3;

var matrix = [];
for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  var index = i % row;
  if(!matrix[index]) matrix[index] = [];
  matrix[index].push(word[i]);
}

// visualization
var table = document.createElement('table');
for(var a = 0; a < matrix.length; a++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for(var b = 0; b < matrix[a].length; b++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.textContent = matrix[a][b];
    tr.append(td);
  }
  table.append(tr);
}
document.body.append(table);
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: .05em .3em;
}
```